# JQuery random number guessing game: loop woes

Tags: javascript, jquery, while-loop, numbers

I am trying to make a simple number guessing game: a random number between 1 and 9999999999 is generated and printed to the console. I want the user to input their guess in a form - and keep looping guesses until the guess matches the random number.

Here is my html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title>Random Number Guess</title>
       
 
   </head>
   
<body>

   <!--text display/button -->

    <p>Try and "guess" the random number! Click "Generate new random number" to start"</p>
 <div id="out1"></div>
 
 <form id="promptUser">
  Your guess:
  <input type="text" id="inUserGuess">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
 <br>
 <button id="btn1">Generate new random number</button>
 <div id="in1"></div>

  
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <script>/*SEE SCRIPT BEOW */</script>
 </body>
 
</html>
```

And here is the javascript/jquery inside:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   /*initialize random number*/
   var randNum = Math.round(Math.exp(Math.random()*Math.log(10000000-0+1)));
   console.log(randNum);


    var win = false;
    while (win = false) {

     $('#promptUser').on('submit', function(e){
      e.preventDefault;

     var userGuess = $('#inUserGuess').val();
     console.log("User guess:" + userGuess);
    });

    /*yes: "congrats! start again"*/
    if (userGuess == randNum){

     console.log("User guess is correct");
     alert("You got it! Try another round.");
     win = true;

    } 
    /*no: "not quite. guess again."*/ 
    else {

     console.log("user guess is incorrect");
     alert("Not quite. Guess again.");
     win = false;
    }
   
   }
```

In order to keep the user guessing until they get it right, I put the guess input inside a while loop and used and if/else statement to determine whether their guess matches the random number.

It seems as though the code gets messed up somewhere before the if/else statement- the console log never shows up. Instead, a new random number is generated when submit is pressed.

I know the syntax of gathering input works - before I attempted to give the user infinite guesses the if statement ran fine (though a new random number was automatically generated after each "play", regardless of correct/incorrect guess)

I feel stupid asking this - but I've been fiddling with it for hours.

[[EDIT]] I now have the submit button event handler doing two things: storing the user input to userGuess and checking to see whether or not it matches randNum, but still is stuck in an infinite loop:

```js
   <script> 



  

   /*initialize random number*/
   var randNum = Math.round(Math.exp(Math.random()*Math.log(10000000-0+1)));
   console.log(randNum);

   var userGuess = "";

   do {

   $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#promptUser').on('submit', function(e){
      e.preventDefault;

     userGuess = $('#inUserGuess').val();
     console.log("User guess:" + userGuess);
     
      
     if(userGuess == randNum){
           console.log("user guess is correct");
           alert("That's right! Play again.");
    
          }  
        else{
     console.log("user guess is incorrect");
     alert("Not quite. Guess again.");
     
      }

    });
  });
  }
   while (userGuess != randNum);
   
   
   
    

    /*generate new random number each on button click */
   $('#btn1').on('click', function(){

    var randNum = Math.round(Math.exp(Math.random()*Math.log(10000000-0+1)));
    console.log(randNum); /*(return random number to console for cheating)*/

   });
 
 
    
       </script>
```

Comment: You can not use while loop like that, it will make an infinite loop. That pattern would have worked with prompt, but that is a blocking action. You need a new design.

Comment: @epascarello I agree that redesign is in order, but the loop isn't acting infinite. Checking the console, it appears each time a guess is submitted, a new random number is generated.

Comment: Because you have a bug `(win = false)` That is `true`, if you had a proper win==false, you would have a browser that would be unresponsive.

Comment: @epascarello Nice catch. I tried changing it just to see, the error that came up is "userGuess is undefined". I am confused as to why, because it is defined in the lines right above. Is there something wrong with the gathering of input, then?

Comment: Because `userGuess ` is out of scope. It is defined in a closure. Plus that code does not run. The code that does the check needs to be in the submit handler. (I am done for the night, have fun figuring it out)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Embarrassingly, still working on it, but have made 'userGuess' a global variable thanks to your suggestion

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the input type not expecting input, unlike prompt()...